# Why can't I trigger a button click event in this Java program?

Tags: java, events, button, awt

I came across a GUI application program made using AWT (Frame) where there's a button called "CLOSE" which on being clicked calls a function **function()**. The book I read it in showed the handling of this event from a **handleEvent()** method. The problem is that the book had a printing mistake for which I couldn't understand the very syntax of triggering the event of the button being clicked. I googled it but couldn't find anything of help. I'm typing a snippet of the code below for your reference. Please help me with the correct syntax.

```
public boolean handleEvent(Event e){
    if(e.get instance of Button){ //this line has a problem
        if(e.arg.equals("CLOSE"){
            function(); //calls a function 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.handleEvent(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just create a class that extends`java.awt.Frame`
and this code in that class work just fine

```
@Override
public boolean handleEvent ( Event evt ) {
    if ( evt.target instanceof Button ) { //this line hasn't a problem
        if ( evt.arg.equals ( "CLOSE" ) ) {
            System.exit ( 0 ); //calls a function 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.handleEvent ( evt );
}
```

Comment: I've tried using `instanceof()` and then put 'Button' as an argument of instanceof(). I tried a couple of things to at least get rid of the syntax error but couldn't.

Comment: People, instead of trying to edit my code, you can also help me by providing me with the code / syntax of handling a button event in an AWT application program based on your knowledge. I just wanna execute a statement when the button is clicked.  And Thanks for giving attention to my problem.

Comment: @ProgyadeepMoulik, I tried,compiled and executed this code with `java.awt.Button Button1 = new java.awt.Button("CLOSE");` and the button close the frame

Comment: @Billydan It worked perfectly. Thanks. **NOTE**: In your answer, the line `System.exit(0);` should be replaced with `function()`.

Answer (score 0):

Judging based on comparison it looks like e.get wants to be `e.getComponent()` on top of what bill said.

```
 if(e.get instance of Button){
```

-needs to be-

```
if(e.getComponent() instanceof Button){
```

Also the return statement I believe here is unreachable. I guess System.exit(0); could fail and it will throw a compilation warning without it.

```
  System.exit(0);
  return true;
```

Comment: if `Event` is the `java.awt.Event` so it hasn't neither `getComponent()` function nor `get` property, may be he is using another example class??

Comment: the clue looks like it lies here `super.handleEvent(e);` looks like it using a function that is overridden, need to see more of the class to see what it extends....or implements and find the method that handleEvent(Event e) has a return type of boolean

Comment: @chewbapocalypse Oh well it was a mistake on my part while typing the code here. I forgot that it wasn't a `System.exit(0)` statement. It called another function `function()` which had `System.exit(0);` following a bunch of other statements. I've edited it. And well I'm using AWT as I've already said in the question.